# Why are these list elements not appearing in a line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the navbar elements appear in a row, side by side, with the dropdown one causing a menu to drop down beneath them.

I know there's the `nav` element and I know there are a thousand jQuery plugins for this. I just want to understand why *this* isn't working.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hjKLD

```
<!-- Works all the way down to IE7! -->

<header>
<nav>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <ul class="drop">
       <li>
           <a href="#">dropdown</a>
       </li>
       <li class="menu">
           <a href="#">link</a>
           <a href="#">link</a>
           <a href="#">link</a>
           <a href="#">link</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>    
</nav>
</header>

li {
 list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ul, li {
    display: inline;
}
```

## Update

I found a quick solution, and without using JavaScript! You might need to make some changes to fix the minor issues.

Here's what I'd suggest for your HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li class="menu">Dropdown
                <ul class="drop">
                    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</header>
```

It's cleaner and more semantic.

Now for the CSS:

```
a, ul, li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
ul {display: inline-block;}
.drop {
    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.menu:hover .drop {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
}
.drop li {display: block;}
```

No JS required.

[Demo via Codepen here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qebrF)

Comment: That almost did it....hover over the dropdown and see the remaining problem. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xfhGt

Comment: @Aerovistae But I provided a solution to *this* question, didn't I?      ; )

Comment: @Aerovistae busy at work now. will fiddle with it and provide a "better" solution soon.

Comment: @Aerovistae I "fixed" it and removed all need for JS. "Fixed" is in quotes because it does not generalize (it is a specific fix to this specific problem). You'll have to find a way to adjust the placement of the drop-down menu for your own site.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add `display: inline;` to the `<li>` element as well. Otherwise, it's still blocked.

Comment: I tried that. Did not work. I'm not doing it right, I'm sure.

Comment: You need it on your `<ul>`, too if you want it to display in line with the `<a>` elements. See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nmlxG

Answer (score 0):

Your list is being displayed as a block element. Which will fill the space horizontaly causing the elements to render vertically.

In order to fix this issue you can chance the display type:

```
display: inline;
display: inline-block;
```

Or you can float the element, which will make it no longer fill horizontally and allow the elements to be displayed side by side:

```
float: left;
```

See here for more details on css display types http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Answer (score 0):

Try this css instead:

```
a{
  vertical-align: top;
}
li {
 list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
ul{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

This will make them all end up on the same row, but something does still need to be done about the dropdown menu pushing the items to the right further when it's shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you searching for:

Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaEkt

For consistency of markup I swapped the `<ul>` list in `<nav>` element.

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <nav class="drop">
      <span>dropdown</span>
      <nav class="menu">
        <a href="#">link</a>

        <a href="#">link</a>

        <a href="#">link</a>

        <a href="#">link</a>
      </nav>
    </nav>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>    
  </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

nav,
ul {
 display: inline-block; 
}

.drop {
  position: relative;
}

.drop .menu {
  position: absolute;
  bootom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This leaves me with one more question...as you have it the four dropdown links appear in a little box directly beneath the dropdown link. What if I want them spread across in a line, four links in a row? The whole row makes up the dropdown menu.